# recursive permutation algorithm in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run a recursive procedure that permutates a given string.
It's compiling on sqldeveloper but when I try to run with input its giving me ora-06502: numeric or value errors on line 13 (the prefix assignment)

```
create or replace 
  procedure print_anagrams
  (pre in varchar2, str in varchar2)
  is
    prefix varchar2(30);
    stringg varchar2(30);
    strlen number;
  begin
    strlen := length(str);
    if strlen = 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line(pre);
    else
      for i in 1..strlen loop
        prefix := pre || SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
        print_anagrams(prefix,stringg);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end;
```

Comment: What are you using as input values?

Comment: The algorithm is wrong. You are adding characters to `prefix` until it finally exceeds 30 in one of the recursive calls and you get your error. How is the algorithm supposed to work? Do you have any description?

Comment: @BobJarvis print_anagrams('', 'cat');

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej its translated from [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html). perm1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two problems:

Firstly, the `LENGTH` function returns `NULL` if its parameter is `NULL`, not 0, so the following condition in your code was never true (because `strlen` is `NULL`):

```
if strlen = 0 then
```

You were getting the `ora-06502: numeric or value errors` error, because, when the `str` argument was empty, the upper range limit of the `FOR LOOP` was `NULL` (because `strlen` is `NULL`):

```
for i in 1..NULL loop
```

And this yields:

```
ora-06502: numeric or value errors
```

Secondly, the last parameter of the `substr` function in Oracle has different meaning than `String`'s `substring` method in Java. In Oracle, that parameter means *"how many characters should be returned"*, whereas in Java it stands for *"end index of the substring to be returned from the original string"*, so the following line should be changed:

```
stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
```

to:

```
stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i - 1) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
```

The change had to be made, because in the Java code that you provided the link to, the loop starts from 0, and 0 is passed as the third argument, which results in an empty string being returned for the first iteration of the loop. Without the change, first iteration in PL/SQL version would return the first character from the argument.

In the end, you get a working procedure:

```
create or replace 
  procedure print_anagrams
  (pre in varchar2, str in varchar2)
  is
    prefix varchar2(30);
    stringg varchar2(30);
    strlen number;
  begin
    strlen := length(str);
    if NVL(strlen, 0) = 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line(pre);
    else
      for i in 1..strlen loop
        prefix := pre || SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i - 1) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
        print_anagrams(prefix,stringg);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end;
/
```

Test:

```
EXEC print_anagrams('', 'cat');
```

Output:

```
cat
cta
act
atc
tca
tac
```

[Oracle Substr Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

[Java String's substring method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)